# Cursor not changing to pointer in Usemap/area case

Tags: html, mouse-cursor

I have the following HTML code which I cannot get to work quite right in all browsers:

```
<div id ="right_header">     
        <img id = "usemapsignin" src="/images/sign-in-panel-wo-FB.png" usemap = "#signin">
</div>      
        <map name = "signin" >
            <area shape = "rect" coords = "30,10, 150, 50" target = "_blank" alt = "signin" id="signin"
                    onMouseOver="document.images['usemapsignin'].style.cursor='pointer'"
            onMouseOut="document.images['usemapsignin'].style.cursor='auto'"/>
            <area shape = "rect" coords = "0,113, 172, 150" target = "_blank" alt = "restowner" id = "restowner"
                onclick = "alert('Hello Restaurant Owner!')"   />
        </map>
```

I am trying to change the cursor to pointer when moved over a part of the usemap. But its not working in Chrome/Safari.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 37):

Chrome and Safari don't support changing the CSS of map or area elements. The only straightforward way to get a mousepointer on an area is to have:

```
<area ... href="javascript:void(0);" />
```

Answer (score 22):

All of these solutions are hacks that don't work well (for me they didn't work at all). After much googling, and more pondering I determined the problem to be that the browser just does not know how to render the area element, therefore it cannot be styled. If you are using HTML5 elements you should be familiar with this challenge. That's when the light bulb went off..

To get around this simply set the area tag to be a block level element. Then you can style it as needed. Worked great for me:

```
area {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Welp, this won't work in IE (go figure).. I'll update my solution when I can circle back to address our old friend IE.

Comment: Nice - Webkit sorted without JS - iE, who cares anymore ?

Comment: For me, seemed like for Safari to show the pointer cursor it indeed did need display: block

Comment: Just tried in IE (8), seems to work there, too. Also Firefox 23 + chrome 33. Great solution. Which version of IE did it not work with?

Comment: if there is no href attribute and an onclick event only, this will not work in IE8 or 10.  Those are the only 2 I tried though...

Comment: Working good in Chrome. in IE - you need to use @Jirapong answer. I'm using twise

Comment: +1 to inon, use both this answer and @Jirapong's to have it all covered.

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 11):

This should work on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```
<img id="img_id" src="image.gif" border="0" usemap="#map4" />
<map id ="map4" name="map4">
    <area  shape ="poly" coords="5, 0, 100, 10, 94, 66, 0, 50" 
           href="javascript:void(0);"
           onmouseover="document.getElementById('img_id').style.cursor='pointer';" 
           onmouseout="document.getElementById('img_id').style.cursor='';"> 
</map>
```

Comment: Working good in IE. in chrome - you need to use @elDuderino answer. I'm using twise

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works fine in latest version of chrome

Answer (score 4):

IE does not support changing cursor in the area tag.

What you have to do is trick it with JS.

```
<img id="someimage" scr="images/image.jpg" usemap="#myareamap" />

<map name="myareamap">
   <area shape="poly" alt="test" title="test" coords="0,0, 50,50, 50,100, 0,100, 0,0"  onmouseover="changeimage('someimage', 'newimagesrc')" />
</map>
```

this is in your javascript

```
function changeimage(id, imagesrc){
    document.getElementById(id).src = imagsrc;
    if (imagesrc = "images/image.jpg"){
       document.getElementById(id).style.cursor = "default";
    } else {
       document.getElementById(id).style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
}
```

This will do two things:

- Will allow you to easily change the image based on the imagemap they scroll over.
- Will give you the illusion that only the part of the areamap scolled over changes the cursor.

Comment: but it want to change cursor only on area not the whole image.

Comment: It is a best answer for me. When mouse leaving area then cursor is no more pointer and when hovering then it is. That's very simple and clever solution, I have not got any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The solution was add the attribute `href="#"` to the area instead of doing a CSS hack.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution using Jquery!

```
$('area').hover(function(){
    //Set your cursor to whatever
    $('body').css('cursor', 'help');
}, function() {
    //set your cursor back to default
    $('body').css('cursor', 'initial');
})
```