# CSS cursor is not working on dynamically added map tag

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, cursor

Here comes my code:

```
function addAlbum(){
    var attr;
    var parent;
    var newelement;

    /*image*/
    newelement = document.createElement("img");
    newelement.src = "criar_album.png";

    attr = document.createAttribute("id");
    attr.value = "addalbum";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("usemap");
    attr.value = "#addalbum_map";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    parent = document.getElementById("content");
    parent.appendChild(newelement);
    /*-----------------------------------------*/

    /*map*/
    newelement = document.createElement("map");

    attr = document.createAttribute("id");
    attr.value = "album_map";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("style"); /*this part is failing I guess*/
    attr.value = "cursor:pointer";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("name");
    attr.value = "addalbum_map";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    parent = document.getElementById("addalbum");
    parent.appendChild(newelement);
    /*-----------------------------------------*/

    /*area*/
    newelement = document.createElement("area");

    attr = document.createAttribute("shape");
    attr.value = "rect";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("coords");
    attr.value = "73, 238, 115, 264";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("onclick");
    attr.value = "createAlbum()";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    attr = document.createAttribute("onmouseover");
    attr.value = "highlightOn(470,320,511,346,2)";
    newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    parent = document.getElementById("album_map");
    parent.appendChild(newelement);
    /*-----------------------------------------*/
}
```

Everything seems to work fine except part of cursor changing whenever I pass it over area element. I have done similar thing with a static image defined in html and it works, so now I'm confused why it doesn't work for dynamically created map?

P.S.: already defined style for "addalbum" id in CSS but it didn't helped. Btw, I know, there are ways to do it by a tricky way like defining href but I wanna know what's the real problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer if you are using chrome or Safari. [Cursor not changing to pointer in Usemap/area case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589768/cursor-not-changing-to-pointer-in-usemap-area-case)

I will add that your code is too complicated. You dont have to add `style`, `id`, `shape` and so on as attributes (`attr.value = "cursor:pointer";` will probably never work at all). The code below works fine, results in a nice 1,1,100,100 map with cursor as pointer. But again works only in browsers like Opera and Firefox, but NOT in Chrome or Safari (WebKit).

```
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src='1.gif';
img.useMap='#album_map';

var map = document.createElement("MAP");
map.id="album_map";
map.style.cursor="pointer"; //the right way

var area  = document.createElement("AREA");
area.shape='rect';
area.coords="1, 1, 100, 100";

map.appendChild(area);
body.appendChild(map);
body.appendChild(img);
```

**adding standard events :**

bind predefined function :

```
function imgClick() {
    alert('click');
}

body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src='image.gif';
img.onclick=imgClick;
body.appendChild(img);
```

or by socalled anonymous function :

```
img.onclick=function() {
    alert('click');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works finally. But still don't make sense to me why it wouldn't work if I append map to the img instead of body. And also one important thing I have noticed - tag attributes are case sensitive. So if I type img.usemap instead of img.useMap it wouldn't work as well.

Comment: You are right. Javascript setters is in "CamelCase", and whenever the CSS-equivalent has a - in its name, like `background-color`, it is `backgroundColor` in javascript. There are setters for all legal CSS-styles for HTML-elements, so it is waste of time trying to create the attributes from scratch.

Comment: Very useful info, thx. And what about attributes like "onmouseover" or "onclick"? Those should be added like this:

`attr = document.createAttribute("onclick");
attr.value = "createAlbum()";
newelement.setAttributeNode(attr);`

?

Comment: see edit. You should search for what params there is available for each standard event, and maybe also how to add listeners in general.