# Javascript / Onclick - Make the mouse cursor a hand when mousing over

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm working with a voting button.

The button was a simple link, but the search engine spiders were crawling the pages and triggering false votes.  So, I changed it to an onclick to make that stop.

However, after doing that, the buttons still work fine, but the mouse cursor no longer has the 'hand' pointer.  It remains the arrow pointer when you mouse-over, so it's hard to tell that it's an actual functioning link.

To attempt to fix this, I added a style="cursor:default;", I also tried style="cursor:crosshair;" to try and change the cursor behavior, but it's not working.  The cursor remains the pointer the whole time.

Here's my code:

```
<map id="vote_buttons" name="vote_buttons">
     <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="5,3,78,43" onClick="window.location='http://www.site.com/page.php?vote=Y'" style="cursor:default;" title="" />
     <area shape="rect" alt="" coords="83,3,160,44" onClick="window.location='http://www.site.com/page.php?vote=N'" style="cursor:pointer;" title="" />
     <area shape="default" nohref="nohref" alt="" />
</map>
```

What am I missing here to make this mouse-over look like a hand?

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: Try `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: I have cursor:pointer; in my example above.  Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I discovered a work around.  I'm not entirely happy with it, but it seems to be doing the job.  Basically, I just added a href="#" to the  tag.  This makes the hand appear and most of the time the click works like it should.

```
<map id="vote_buttons" name="vote_buttons">
     <area href="#" shape="rect" alt="" coords="5,3,78,43" onClick="window.location='http://www.site.com/page.php?vote=Y'" style="cursor:default;" title="" />
     <area href="#"  shape="rect" alt="" coords="83,3,160,44" onClick="window.location='http://www.site.com/page.php?vote=N'" style="cursor:pointer;" title="" />
</map>
```

Comment: You could also add full url to href (instead of #) and remove onClick.

Comment: This is "wrong" in so many levels: 
* Adding a fake href just to show the pointer cursor is not a good practice.
* Using onclick event just for redirecting (instead of using href) is also a bad habit.
* Not using css for a style related issue is also a bad practice.

I think the bes approach should be as stated before adding "cursor: pointer;" to the proper css file with the proper selector.

Comment: @David Diez - If you read my post, you'll see my code has the solution you are proposing.  That didn't work in my situation, which is why I'm here in the first place.  LOL...but thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Woops, you are totally right! Truly sorry. If you edit your answer I'll upvote it. I don't know what I was doing when I wrote that last year ><U

Answer (score 49):

You can do this in css!

just add this to the element you want the style.

```
cursor:pointer;
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually I found the answer here: [Cursor not changing to pointer in Usemap/area case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589768/cursor-not-changing-to-pointer-in-usemap-area-case)

In your case, just add the `href="javascript:void(0)"` to each `<area>`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yE5bQ/

Comment: Actually you can only href="javascript;"

Comment: From my testing, href="javascript;" tries to load a page "/javscript;" and issues a 404, I believe the comment encouraging that is WRONG/BAD. That's on Chrome 97.x.x

Answer (score 8):

In your CSS put this:

```
#vote_buttons {
    cursor:hand;
}
```

This will make it so that your cursor turns into a hand while hovering over the button.

Answer (score -3):

Try this above head, it works in **IE** and **HTA's**, trick was to include **URL**...

```
<!-- put the following code inside your [body] button or anchor -->

<!-- onmousedown="mouseDown1()" onmouseup="mouseOut1()" -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function mouseDown1() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'url(anim2.cur)';
}

function mouseOut1() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'url(anim1.cur)';
}

function calc() {
var dummy = 0;

for (var i=0; i<100000;i++) {
     for (var z=0; i<100000;i++) {
          dummy = dummy + z + i;
     }
}

cursor_clear();
}

</script>
```