# Change Cursor on Portion of Image

Tags: css

I have a circular image. How do I change the cursor only on the circle part, not the whole square? If it makes any difference, the rest of the image is transparent.

Comment: Something like this: 
[Answered already?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589768/cursor-not-changing-to-pointer-in-usemap-area-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding something like this?

```
.circular {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
}

<div class="circular"><img src="http://link-to-your/image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```