# Apply cursor css to area map

Tags: html, css

I have a html map

```css
#world {
  position: relative;
  cursor: url("http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images4/cur395.gif"), url("http://i50.tinypic.com/21b9fso.gif"), auto;
}
area {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="world">
  <map id="world">
    <area shape="circle" alt="Africa" title="Africa" coords="682,462,97" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="afr.style.visibility='visible'; afr.src='http://irvingglobalstudies.wikispaces.com/file/view/Africa.png/174406561/284x300/Africa.png';"
    onmouseout="afr.style.visibility='hidden';" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Americas" title="Americas" coords="228,198,123" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="ame.style.visibility='visible'; ame.src='https://www.walmartethics.com/images/landingpagemap/americas.png';" onmouseout="ame.style.visibility='hidden';"
    />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Asia/Pacific" title="Asia/Pacific" coords="1110,412,122" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="asi.style.visibility='visible'; asi.src='http://www.awlgrip.com/PublishingImages/AsiaPacific.png';" onmouseout="asi.style.visibility='hidden';"
    />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Europe" title="Europe" coords="627,136,98" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="eur.style.visibility='visible'; eur.src='http://scrubs.co.uk/_img/map-europe.png';" onmouseout="eur.style.visibility='hidden';" />
  </map>
  <img alt="Africa" style="position:absolute;top:559px;left:779px;visibility:hidden;" id="afr" src="http://irvingglobalstudies.wikispaces.com/file/view/Africa.png/174406561/284x300/Africa.png" />
  <img alt="Americas" style="position:absolute;top:321px;left:351px;visibility:hidden;" id="ame" src="https://www.walmartethics.com/images/landingpagemap/americas.png" />
  <img alt="Asia/Pacific" style="position:absolute;top:534px;left:1232px;visibility:hidden;" id="asi" src="http://www.awlgrip.com/PublishingImages/AsiaPacific.png" />
  <img alt="Europe" style="position:absolute;top:234px;left:725px;visibility:hidden;" id="eur" src="http://scrubs.co.uk/_img/map-europe.png" />
  <img alt="world map" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/No_colonies_blank_world_map.png" usemap="#world" />
</div>
<img alt="Ta Da" src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/008/119/1353379_700b.png" />
```

The cursor is correct when over the map itself and reverts correctly when over tada.png but the cursor doesn't change when hovering over the area shapes as expected.
What element should I be referring to to change the cursor when it is over the map circles?

Comment: can you share demo link?

Comment: I created http://jsfiddle.net/FiveBs/5w5jfxgz/ but can't see the result due to company security settings.

Comment: here cursor same in whole page? I am not getting, plz explain

Comment: There are two images; the cursor is an aeroplane when over the world map but reverts to auto when over the cartoon woman. There are several circles on the map and the cursor is not changing as expected when hovering over those circles. The cursor should revert to auto there too.

Comment: Hye @jason Stallard, you want to cursor:airoplane icon on area map, if I am not wrong?

Comment: Why the edit @Ruslan López Carro?

Comment: Because it was just a bunch of code and I've seen that answers increase with StackOverflow fiddles :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `<area>` elements have a `href` attribute the `auto` behavior for a cursor is to be a `pointer`. If you want the default mouse cursor you need to change your CSS to.

```
area {
    cursor: default;
}
```

[Here is your JSFiddle updated with this change](http://jsfiddle.net/076b7pg5/)

Other CSS Cursor options can be found [listed at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: Neither my fiddle or yours worked on EI11 so I decided to check on Chrome46 and they both work :s

Comment: I wanted the pointer but it doesn't work on IE11. I'm giving the answer tick to @Simon-West as his fiddle made me realise the browser specific nature of my problem.

Comment: In an answer to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589768/cursor-not-changing-to-pointer-in-usemap-area-case)  one user states that IE does not support changing cursors on an area tag. He dosn't provide a source and I have struggled to find any documentation that I could link to "prove" it. If I find anything I'll update the answer to include IEs peculiar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

CSS

```
.circle:hover
{
    cursor: url("http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images4/cur395.gif"), url("http://i50.tinypic.com/21b9fso.gif"), auto;
}
```